# ksh single quotes vs double quotes

Tags: quotes, ksh

I'm learning ksh, I'm trying to run a command using a subshell, but I got different results, I'm guessing the reason.

```
root@setPrompt[/home/za] X=$("ls -ltr")
ksh: ls -ltr:  not found.
root@setPrompt[/home/za] X=$('ls -ltr')
ksh: ls -ltr:  not found.
root@setPrompt[/home/za] X="$(ls -ltr)"
root@setPrompt[/home/za] echo $X
total 5256 -rw-
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$()` runs the enclosed command in a subshell and returns its output.  Your first two examples are trying to run the command `"ls -ltr"`.  Since you've quoted the entire command, the shell is going to look for a command whose entire name `ls -ltr`, not one whose name is `ls` and is being passed the options `-ltr`.  The third example runs the command `ls`, with the argument `-ltr` and X gets the output of that command.  Since the `$()` was enclosed by double-quotes, field splitting and pathname expansion are not performed.

An example of the difference:

```
$ ls
bin
$ echo $(echo 'b*')
bin
$ echo "$(echo 'b*')"
b*
```

See also the [SUS specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) for command expansion.

Answer (score -2):

It probably didn't inherit the environment. If the path is not set then it can't find the ls program

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with the environment or path. jamessan's answer is correct in that it has everything to do with quoting rules, parameter expansion, and command substitution.